# Electronic Ignition

Tags: automotive

I have a friend online and he gave me a schematic to make an Electronic ignition module for motorcycle, I just want to know that if this is the working circuit? also I m not getting some parts here in India. If you may add any easily available parts. ss351At not available here. BAT54 not found also want to add a LED for blinking signal so I can see if module working or not. some question in my mind. I saw BAT54 has 3 pins and this schematic has only 2 pins. Also R1 is connected with ground, is it pullup resistor? and why on negative side?
Please redraw with correct( if incorrect)
[image]

Comment: I think your question is too broad and contains too many smaller quetsions. To get a response, you might want to ask a single, more specific question instead of 'design me something' for 10points.

Comment: can anyone try to remake and correct this schematic? I want to give a try to make it for my motorcycle.

Answer (score 1):

R1 is a pull-DOWN intended to keep the gate of the NFET closed.
BAT54 comes in a few flavors; the one in the schematic is the single-diode version (with 3 pins).

Edit (per mkeith): BAT54, really?! This should be a ~15-16V zener.

The "hall sensor" most-likely includes biasing and a transistor/darlington pair that is not shown in the schematic. In any case, a typical FET could withstand 20V, so clamping it slightly above the alternators voltage will keep it inactive but ready, just in case.

Here is the "original" semi-solid-state ignition design; this design has been upgraded, over time, with parts being replaced or added for protection of the components and/or stabilization of it's operating point. Manufacturers re-design and re-implement this circuit and change the names of the signals "every 4 years" but the function remains constant:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAEdR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 is ballast, providing weak ground to coil.
The NPN provides a strong, sudden, ground and the coil reacts.

At their heart, ignition systems are just "boost converters".

Comment: Where appropriate, the left-most coil is replaced with a battery. The Lpickup segment has been re-re-re-designed many different ways over the years, including the Hall sensor you are using.

Comment: Can you explain how the BAT54 protects the NFET gate? I think it is a mistake. It is supposed to be a zener, but someone accidentally put in a BAT54. I am open to the idea that I am wrong.

Comment: @mkeith, good catch. Also, since the FET is controlled by a hall sensor, I'm not sure where an (unplanned) over-voltage would come from to begin with. If the alternator supplies 14ish volts, the hall would put out 14ish volts too and the FET wouldn't take issue anyway.. ??

Comment: @mkeith, I've never thought to scope my truck. Do alternators put out high transients, above 20ish volts? 7.5k for R1 seems like a pretty specific number, as well; I'd like to know why.

Comment: Not my field, but I believe there can be pretty nasty transients. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_dump